# What does the < operator in ActionController::Base < mod mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came across this piece of code in [Rails action pack gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.9/actionpack/lib/action_controller/integration.rb#L307-311) (2.3.9)

```
[ControllerCapture, ActionController::ProcessWithTest].each do |mod|
  unless ActionController::Base < mod # what does this comparison mean?
    ActionController::Base.class_eval { include mod }
  end
end
```

I am trying to understand the second line in the code shown above. What does the `<` operator do in this context? Is it the standard comparison operator?(if so how do you explain the code?)

Comment: I changed the title to be a bit more descriptive. You can change it back if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information on these operators can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001669).

For `<` it reads:

**mod < other → true, false, or nil**

> Returns true if mod is a subclass of
>   other. Returns nil if there‘s no
>   relationship between the two. (Think
>   of the relationship in terms of the
>   class definition: "class A < B" implies
>   "A < B").

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/blob/62769002bd59e0b1dd05/kernel/common/module.rb#L550-561) of this method implemented in Rubinius.